# Spinner with label/hint/placeholder inside always visible

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is it possible to have a Spinner in Android with a label that is always visible?

For example a spinner that indicates a gender.
The left side of the spinner should have the label ("gender").
The right side of the spinner should have the value.

[image]

I got a few problems with this:

- gravity property of the spinner does not show the text on the right
  if set to right.
- spinner has no label/hint/placeholder property?
- using a textview with property labelfor set to the id of the spinner 
  does not work.

Comment: what about a TextView that is `toLeftOf` a Spinner that contains "gender" as its text? Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you want, can you post an illustration?

Comment: Creating a customSpinner will be the correct answer. If the basic android widgets doesn't support your functionality. Create a custom one (keep in mind to respect Android design guidelines)

Comment: Yeah I guess that is true. But wanted to know if there was a way to do it without creating a custom spinner.

Comment: It could be achieved with a TextView and a Spinner and some clever background resources that make them appear to be part of the same "Widget". But making a custom one would be prefered probably so that clicks on the TextView lbl can count for the spinner also.